# There is a black background behind my list item and I want it to be transparent

Tags: html, css, background, background-color, rgba

There is an image behind this list, how do I style the list correctly so there is no black background behind it?

```
<div>
  <img src="image.png">
  <ul>
    <li id="1"> 1 </li>
    <li id="2"> 2 </li>
    <li id="3"> 3 </li>
    <li id="4"> 4 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here are my styles:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
}
```

I use `rgba(0,0,0,0)` yet behind the text there is a black background rather than transparent.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you please provide the code necessary to reproduce your problem? The code you have posted doesn't seem to result in what you are describing for me.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the issue for faster troubleshooting - the code provided does not reflect the issue as described

Comment: Nobody could help you because we do not know your IMG address, could you please add an example that can working? Thanks.

Comment: @robere2 I added my styles to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the styles of all the parents or give a desired background color on ul